# Python list to dictionnary with indexes

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to convert a list :

```
[A, B, A, A, B, C]
```

to a dictionnary with each item and the indexes where it was found :

```
{ A : [0,2,3], B : [1,4], C : [5] }
```

Any idea of an efficient way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict` and `enumerate`:

```
>>> lst = ['a','b','a','a','b','c']
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i, value in enumerate(lst):
...     d[value].append(i)
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [0, 2, 3], 'c': [5], 'b': [1, 4]})
```

Or, this can be accomplished with a plain `dict`, although, it is usually slower:

```
>>> lst = ['a','b','a','a','b','c']
>>> d = {}
>>> for i, value in enumerate(lst):
...     d.setdefault(value, []).append(i)
...
>>> d
{'a': [0, 2, 3], 'c': [5], 'b': [1, 4]}
```

You could have, of course, converted the `defaultdict` to a `dict`:

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [0, 2, 3], 'c': [5], 'b': [1, 4]})
>>> dict(d)
{'a': [0, 2, 3], 'c': [5], 'b': [1, 4]}
>>> help(dict)
```

Comment: @MYGz sure. It might not be obvious that `dict` can take a mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C']
print {i:[j[0] for j in enumerate(lst) if j[1] == i] for i in set(lst)}
```

**Result**

```
{'A': [0, 2, 3], 'B': [1, 4], 'C': [5]}
```

Comment: You don't need to access the tuple by indices, Use tuple unpacking directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension and a dict comprehension. Create a set out of the list first. Then you can easily use enumerate and do this.

```
>>> l = ["A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C"]
>>> {i:[j for j,k in enumerate(l) if k==i] for i in set(l)}
{'C': [5], 'B': [1, 4], 'A': [0, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: This is inefficient. You do a pass on `l` when you do `set(l)`, and then you do `k` more passes where `k` is the number of unique elements in `l`.